# TypeError: Attempted to wrap which is already wrapped

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

My codes:

```
  before(function _before() {
    this.myObject = new MyObject();
  });
  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    const stubLog = sinon.stub(this.myObject.log, 'warn');
  }));
  it('should 2', sinon.test(function() {
    const stubLog = sinon.stub(this.myObject.log, 'warn');
  }));
```

sinon version: 1.17.6

Why I got the error `TypeError: Attempted to wrap warn which is already wrapped` in should 2 test? Should I restore `stubLog` manually? I think `sinon.test()` will do it for me. Maybe I did something wrong?

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried using `this.stub()` instead of `sinon.stub()` inside the sandbox?

```
const stubLog = this.stub(this.myObject.log, 'warn');
```

From the [official docs](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon-test#why), an example:

```
it('should do something', sinonTest(function(){
    var spy1 = this.spy(myFunc);
    var spy2 = this.spy(myOtherFunc);
    myFunc(1);
    myFunc(2);
    assert(spy1.calledWith(1));
    assert(spy1.calledWith(2));
}));
```

Once wrapped with `sinon.test()`, the function would access the `this` pointer inside itself and use it to stub/spy other functions.

Using it like that should restore your stubs automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you need to reset the stub before creating another one. You can do this using stub.reset() or stub.restore(), ideally inside beforeEach.

https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/